# React: Input onChange to update state step behind

Tags: reactjs, input, state, onchange

I have an input with `onChange` attribute which calls a function `handleChange`, which updates state with the new value that was typed in the input.

**Issue 1** - When state is logged at the end of `handleChange` it contains the old state, or one input letter behind (will log 'ca' when you type 'cat').

**Issue 2** - Without `event.persist` the event is 'synthetic' and doesn't contain the value. Is this acceptable to keep the `persist` or should this be structured differently?

Input has:

`onChange={this.handleChange}`

Which calls function:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    event.persist() // without this the event is 'synthetic'

    const newTerms = {...this.state.terms}
    newTerms.text = event.target.value

    this.setState({terms: newTerms})

    console.log('state', this.state) //logs the previous state
}
```

`this.state.terms.text` should be changed:

```
this.state = {
    terms: {
        text: '',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

state update is asyncronous. What you want is this:

```
this.setState({terms: newTerms}, () => console.log('state', this.state))
```

Even without `persist` the event contains the value inside the event handler. This is only true in a synchronous context, so you should not pass the event to `setState` or other asynchronous methods.